# ATI Radeon 4200 has graphics and performance issue; how to rectify?

Tags: ati, graphics, games, radeon

I have a ATI Radeon 4200 graphics card. When ever I launch runescape the graphics tear and get shifted all over the place. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Your card is no longer supported by AMD in the latest catalyst driver. Sadly you won't be able to install a older driver either. It wont support the current X Display server on Ubuntu 12.04. You would find better performance by removing the driver by going to your "additional drivers" menu in your system settings, then clicking remove.

I hate to say this your Ubuntu experience wouldn't be that great on that machine. You would need to upgrade to a newer machine to see Ubuntu in it's true colors. I would recommend any of the Core series from Intel, with a Nvidia Geforce 500 series graphics card.

Hope this helps! Cheers :)